# Asp.Net MVC 5 The ActionLink Only Calls The Action Method in The First Time When I Click on It

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an e-commerce website. What I'm trying to do right now is when users click on the "Open Modal" link, a modal dialog will open and show the product detail.

At the first time when I click on the ActionLink, it will call the QuickView action method in the Product controller and show the detail information of the product. However, when I click on the ActionLink for another product, it won’t call the QuickView action method. Also, the content of the modal dialog still displays the information of the previous product. Basically, the problem is that the action method only gets called in the first time that I click on the ActionLink. The action method won’t get called anymore when I click on the ActionLink again. When I right-click the page and inspect the element, I can see that the modal action link is generated correctly. I’m so confused about it. Please help.

The main view:

```
<div id="product">
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", product)
    }
</div>

// The normal bootstrap modal with out any content in the modal-content div. Note that the id matches the data_target from the link
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade product_view" tabindex="-1" 
   role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    // The normal bootstrap behavior is to only grab the content for the 
    // modal once, if you need to pull in different partial views then the data on 
    // the modal will have to be cleared.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            $('#modal-container .modal-content').empty();
        });
    });

    // callback from form modal
    function success() {
        alert("Success!");
    }
</script>
```

The product summary:

```
    <div class="caption">
        <h4 class="pull-right">@Model.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
        <h4>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(Model.Name, "ProductDetail", new { productId = Model.ProductID, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, 
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="space-ten"></div>
    <div class="btn-ground text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new { ProductId = Model.ProductID})'">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Cart
        </button>

        <div>
            // Create a link that calls the controller method that returns the partial view
            @Html.ActionLink("Open Modal", "QuickView", "Product", new { ProductId = Model.ProductID }, new
            {
                // Needed to link to the html of the modal
                data_target = "#modal-container",
                // Tells the bootstrap javascript to do its thing
                data_toggle = "modal"
            })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-ten"></div>
</div>
```

The quick view:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="class pull-right"><span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <h3 class="modal-title">@Model.Name</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 product_img">
            <img 
src="http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5613/5613060_sd.jpg" 
class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 product_content">
        <h3 class="cost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> @Model.Price </h3>
        <div class="space-ten"></div>
        <div class="btn-ground">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add To Cart</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add To Wishlist</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The action method in the product contorller:

```
    public ActionResult QuickView(int productId)
    {
        Product prod = repository.Products
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

        return PartialView(prod);
    }
```

[image of the inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YteKi.png)

Comment: It's because when ajax is done. your dom changes. you need to access it from another ajax or $(document).on(event,selector,function)

Comment: i feel `$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function ()` isn't firing. hence its not clearing the previous data. Using ajax would be really easy to implement this scenario instead of direct actionCall via ActionLink.

Comment: @ecKO Thanks for your response. I use the Html.ActionLink, not the Ajax.Action for that. If you have the solution, can you provide me the code snippet, please?

Comment: Thanks @Kumar_Vikas I need to pass the ProductId to the action method to let it search the product in the database, and return it as a model to the view so the modal dialog can get the product detail. However, the action method only gets called at the first time I click on it. Can you provide me an example of how to fix it please?

Comment: @IYU Can you include the controller's code as well for partial that returns the modal?

Comment: @IYU And yes using ajax it will be done in seconds, just make sure to add controller's code as well.

Comment: @ecKO Thank you, your solution really makes the action link call the action method. However, when I set a break point in the action method that being called by the action link, I find out that the action method is being called so many times by different worker threads which cause performance issue of popping out the modal dialog. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you calling the actionlink directly on the page? could you update the code so i can have a look.

Comment: @ecKO Yes, I'm calling the action link directly from the view. I just add the code for the action method to the post. And you can scroll down to see the answer that I post to see the update of the view. Basically, I just update the script and change the action link type from html to ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who gives me the suggestion. In order to fix the issue, I need to combine the solutions that provide by @Anthony McGrath, @ecKO and @Kumar_Vikas.

Here is the solution:

As @Anthony McGrath mention:

Change the script from:

```
$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $('#modal-container .modal-content').empty();
});
```

to:

```
var emptyModalContent = function() {
    $('#modal-container').removeData('bs.modal').find('.modal-
content').empty();
};

$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    emptyModalContent();
});
```

After that, follow @ecKO and @Kumar_Vikas' idea and change the action link that calls the action method from @Html.ActionLink to @Ajax.ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the modal content is empty before the action link tries to call the server.

You have javascript code which seems like it clears the modal content whenever the modal gets hidden. Is it possible that the modal still has content when you click an action link after the first time?

**EDIT:**

Try adding an onclick function that empties the modal content when the action link is clicked. So add the onclick property in your ActionLink call by changing your code like below:

change this:

```
$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $('#modal-container .modal-content').empty();
});
```

to:

```
var emptyModalContent = function() {
    $('#modal-container').removeData('bs.modal').find('.modal-content').empty();
};

$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    emptyModalContent();
});
```

and add onclick property to action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Open Modal", "QuickView", "Product", new { ProductId = Model.ProductID }, new
            {
                // Needed to link to the html of the modal
                data_target = "#modal-container",
                // Tells the bootstrap javascript to do its thing
                data_toggle = "modal",
                onclick = "emptyModalContent()"
            })
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I'm pretty sure that the modal dialog still has the html content from the previous product. Base on my knowledge, I think the action method should be called when users click on the action link. Do you know how to fix the script?

Comment: Thank you, your code really helps me a lot. But it needs to changes the Html.ActionLInk to Ajax.ActionLink. One more question, why do I need to clear the previous html content in the modal box?